# Android: Wrong RGB values in Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, rgb

I have created a png in gimp and I am reading it as bitmap in Android.
When I deploy the app on Galaxy Tab 10.1 (**ICS**) I get the right rgb values, but in emulator and on Xperia Arc (**Android 2.3.3**) I get slightly different rgb values.

**For Example**
I set a pixel value to (255, 255, 200) in gimp and export png. When I create a bitmap from resource (while using emulator/Xperia Arc using 2.3.3) I get values (255, 255, 206), while on Galaxy Tab/emulator (using 4.0 (ICS)) I get the right values (255, 255, 200)

I am not sure why is that. Can show you guys the code if it helps.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the emulator is performing gamma correction. Monitors typically have a gamma value of around 1.2. Any RGB channel value you send to the monitor (0.0–1.0) will be raised to that exponent before display. The emulator appears to be using a gamma of [around 0.87](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=floor%28%28200/255%29%5Ex%20255%29%20=%20206) to compensate. Although the *values* will differ, colours on the emulator will more closely match those on the device.

Comment: Hi, I think it has to do with Android 4.0 and Android 2.3.3, 4.0 emulator shows correct values while 2.3.3 emulator does not (same is the case with actual devices). I have edited my question, I think you read the old one, anyhow I think its android version issue.